# Gather or pivot_longer on multiple columns?

Tags: r

This is the data that I have:

```
id<-c(1:7)
emp1<-c('ft','ft','pt','pt','ft','no','no')
emp2<-c('ft','ft','ft','ft','no','pt','ft')
marstat1<-c('married','married','divorced','single','single','single','single')
marstat2<-c('divorced','married','divorced','single','single','married','single')
df<-data.frame(id,emp1,emp2,marstat1,marstat2)
```

I want to reshape (from wide to long) it into

```
id<-c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7)
year<-c(rep(1:2,7))
emp<-c('ft','ft','ft','ft','pt','ft','pt','ft','ft','no','no','pt','no','ft')
marstat<-c('married','divorced','married','married','divorced','divorced','single','single','single','single','single','married','single','single')
df2<-data.frame(id,year,emp,marstat)
```

I tried to use dplyr::gather, but it gives me 4 rows each id instead of 2. And it's not clear to me what to do with the year dimension (I don't need two columns of year, just one)

```
df2<-df %>% 
  gather(key='year',value='emp',emp1,emp2) %>% 
  gather(key='year2',value='marstat',marstat1,marstat2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this approach

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(matches("\\d$"), names_to = c("name", "year"), names_pattern = "([^\\d]+)(\\d+)$") %>% 
  pivot_wider()
```

First, transform the dataframe into one with only three columns `id`, `nameyear`, and `value`; concurrently separate the second column `nameyear` into `name` and `year`. Then, just pivot the two columns `name` and `value` wider.

Output

```
# A tibble: 14 x 4
      id year  emp   marstat 
   <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>   
 1     1 1     ft    married 
 2     1 2     ft    divorced
 3     2 1     ft    married 
 4     2 2     ft    married 
 5     3 1     pt    divorced
 6     3 2     ft    divorced
 7     4 1     pt    single  
 8     4 2     ft    single  
 9     5 1     ft    single  
10     5 2     no    single  
11     6 1     no    single  
12     6 2     pt    married 
13     7 1     no    single  
14     7 2     ft    single
```

Comment: Beautiful! I'm going to keep a note of this. Very useful! Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. That worked! I don't understand these parts: "\\d$", "([^\\d]+)(\\d+)$")...but I am guessing this is base R grammar on finding numeric or character strings?

Comment: No, those are regular expressions. See [this](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/articles/regular-expressions.html) for more information. @kna123

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this can be useful for you:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
newdf <- df %>% select(c('id',starts_with('emp'))) %>%
  pivot_longer(-id) %>%
  mutate(name=gsub('emp','',name)) %>%
  rename(emp=value,year=name) %>%
  left_join(
    df %>% select(c('id',starts_with('marstat'))) %>%
      pivot_longer(-id) %>%
      mutate(name=gsub('marstat','',name)) %>%
      rename(marstat=value,year=name)
  )
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 14 x 4
      id year  emp   marstat 
   <int> <chr> <fct> <fct>   
 1     1 1     ft    married 
 2     1 2     ft    divorced
 3     2 1     ft    married 
 4     2 2     ft    married 
 5     3 1     pt    divorced
 6     3 2     ft    divorced
 7     4 1     pt    single  
 8     4 2     ft    single  
 9     5 1     ft    single  
10     5 2     no    single  
11     6 1     no    single  
12     6 2     pt    married 
13     7 1     no    single  
14     7 2     ft    single
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant solution, but this would work:

```
pivot_longer(df, cols=starts_with("marstat"), names_to="year", names_prefix="marstat", values_to="marstat") %>% 
pivot_longer(cols=starts_with("emp"), names_to="empyear", names_prefix="emp", values_to="emp") %>% 
filter(year==empyear) %>% 
select(-empyear)
```

What this does is two consecutive pivots, followed by removing the lines where the year number isn't identical, and finally removing the superfluous year column. Note that "names_prefix" allows you to remove the text part of marstat1/2 and emp1/2, but you still end up with a `chr` vector, which you will need to turn into an integer if you need that.

Give you this:

```
A tibble: 14 x 4
      id year  marstat  emp  
   <int> <chr> <fct>    <fct>

 1     1 1     married  ft   
 2     1 2     divorced ft   
 3     2 1     married  ft   
 4     2 2     married  ft   
 5     3 1     divorced pt   
 6     3 2     divorced ft   
 7     4 1     single   pt   
 8     4 2     single   ft   
 9     5 1     single   ft   
10     5 2     single   no   
11     6 1     single   no   
12     6 2     married  pt   
13     7 1     single   no   
14     7 2     single   ft
```